# How to prevent hidden columns from appearing after JTable redraws its table

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am creating a JTable that allows users to hide specific columns and/or rows from view.  To hide the columns I am using the removeColumn method in JTable to remove the column that is responsible for displaying data.  To remove the rows, I had to implement a method in my Table Model, which extends AbstractTableModel, to remove the row from the backing data and then called the fireTablesRowDeleted(rowIndex, rowIndex).

All this works fine except if I delete a row after hiding a column the column gets unhidden because the fireTablesRowDeleted method redraws the table from scratch.  Is there a way to prevent the hidden columns from reappearing?  I tried to keep a list of all the hidden column indexes, so I could re-hide them once the call to removeRow returned, but that seemed to not work.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: _fireTablesRowDeleted method redraws the table from scratch_ - no, by default the table doesn't, so it's something wrong in the code you ar not showing.

Comment: You have to keep track of the deleted columns somewhere in your GUI model, and after any operation that redraws the entire table, re-hide your columns based on your GUI model.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Thanks for the suggestion, I got it up and running now!